# Definition of elliptic curve, base point

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field. Elliptic curve $E/K$ is defined as a genus 1 curve with base point $O$  (for example, in Silverman's book chapter 3).

But in this definition, what is a correct definition of base point ?

I have never seen mention about the definition of base point.

I think 'base point' refers to identity element as a group, or point at infinity of Weierstrass form, but these 'intuitive' explanation does not define correctly the notion 'base point'. It is not the same notion as rational point of $E$, how can we define 'base point' correctly ?

Comment: It’s just any chosen $K$-rational point on $E$. Then you use that point for defining the addition on $E$.

Comment: "Base point" just means a distinguished point on the curve. The operation will then be defined in a way that makes the base point the identity. But at the definition stage it just means you have a "pointed curve of genus 1", much like the definition of [pointed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set?wprov=sfti1) or a [pointed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_space?wprov=sfti1).